# Using application context in quartz job

Tags: grails

I am trying to read message bundle in a job (Grails 2.0, Quartz-0.4.2):

```
class Job1Job {
 def timeout = 5000l // execute job once in 5 seconds
 def grailsApplication

 def execute() {
   def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
   def bean = ctx.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')
   println bean.message(code:'default.home.label')
 }
}
```

And get error:

```
Error 2011-12-28 14:30:14,021 [quartzScheduler_Worker-5] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occured in job: GRAILS_JOBS.testappcontext.Job1Job
Message: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

The code works perfectly in controller and service. What I am doing wrong ? 
I suspect this code run perfectly in grails 1.3.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going the long way around - just use what the taglib uses, the `messageSource` bean:

```
class Job1Job {
   long timeout = 5000 // execute job once in 5 seconds
   def messageSource

   void execute() {
      println messageSource.getMessage('default.home.label', null, Locale.default)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to pass message parameter ? my code doesn't work:     messageSource.getMessage('default.list.label',["!"], Locale.default)

Comment: The 2nd arg is an Object array, so that should be `messageSource.getMessage('default.list.label', ['!'] as Object[], Locale.default)`